# How in JMeter can you write a function that includes or can be used to generate random using time function with milliseconds

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I need to create a random number using time function in JMeter that creates milliseconds too.

How in JMeter can you write a function that includes or can be used to generate random using time function with milliseconds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below:-

```
${__longSum(${__time()},${__Random(1,50)},MYVAR)}
```

Hope it help.

Comment: Thank  you very much for your help